# How to fetch data from a table matching multiple filters?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 different tables: tbl_records, tbl_users

I want to fetch all data from tbl_records, which is published by f_name='Kr' and which are inserted today (date of record).

[image: Image of database structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns all columns from tbl_records for the user with the f_name 'Kr', with date_of_record on or later than midnight today.

```
SELECT r.* FROM tbl_records r
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE r.date_of_record >= DATE(NOW()) AND u.f_name LIKE 'Kr'
```

Though it's usually better to specify the exact columns you want, in case the table definition is changed later:

```
SELECT r.user_id, r.status, r.date_of_record FROM tbl_records r
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON r.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE r.date_of_record >= DATE(NOW()) AND u.f_name LIKE 'Kr'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_records AS tr JOIN tbl_users AS tu ON ( tr.user_id = tu.user_id ) AND tr.date_of_record = DATE(NOW()) AND tu.f_name = 'kr'
```

Comment: It looks like the image with the question has been updated since you answered.